# chart.js legend strikethrough not working

Tags: javascript, html, angular, chart.js

I am currently working with Chart.js to create a Doughnut chart. My goal is to update a variable's value when a legend item is clicked. While I have successfully implemented the functionality to show/hide data upon legend item clicks, I encountered an issue with applying a strikethrough effect to the legend item.

more, can see the hidden value is chnaging but not legend text chnage with strikethrough:

Code:

```
public doughnutChartOptions: ChartConfiguration<'doughnut'>['options'] = {
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: true,
        onClick: (evt, legendItem, legend) => {
          console.log('Indx', legendItem.datasetIndex, legendItem.index)
          const index = legendItem.index;
          const ci = legend.chart;

          ci.data.datasets[0].data[index] = ci.data.datasets[0].data[index]==0 ? this.entitle[this.year][this.code][legendItem.text] : 0
          
          legendItem.hidden = true    // Hiddend is not wokring
          //ci.legend.chart.legend.legendItems[index].hidden = ci.data.datasets[0].data[index]==0         // also tried this way but still not working
           
          console.log('~~~',legendItem.hidden) //can see value updating

          this.holiShow = !this.holiShow;
          ci.update();

          },
      },
    },
    cutout: '80%',
  };
```

Comment: StackBlitz example might help getting an answer

Comment: Hi @BojanKogoj thnks for reply, on stackBlitz seems its seems woking fine just a little bit slow.   https://stackblitz.com/edit/chartjs-doughnut-chart-xfc89d?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I believe `.update()` is resetting the hidden value. No idea why though

Comment: Yes, .update() is causing the issue, but I update hiddend value after update() its works for me.